# Distance (in px) between two elements in the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I get the distance between two elements in the DOM?

I am thinking on using [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect), but I fail to see how can I use that in order to calculate the distance between two elements. So, for example, how close is a  from an .

Comment: Are you trying to find the difference between the two elements' top left corners?

Comment: I am actually looking for the best way to find the distance. I am not sure if finding the difference between the two elements' top left corners would be it. Ideally would be the center of both elements no?

Comment: Depends what your ultimate goal is. But I'll answer based on that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretend you have a div with id `div1` and a div with id `div2`. You could calculate the distance (in pixels) from `div1`'s center to `div2`'s center with some simple math...

```
// get the bounding rectangles
var div1rect = $("#div1")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
var div2rect = $("#div2")[0].getBoundingClientRect();

// get div1's center point
var div1x = div1rect.left + div1rect.width/2;
var div1y = div1rect.top + div1rect.height/2;

// get div2's center point
var div2x = div2rect.left + div2rect.width/2;
var div2y = div2rect.top + div2rect.height/2;

// calculate the distance using the Pythagorean Theorem (a^2 + b^2 = c^2)
var distanceSquared = Math.pow(div1x - div2x, 2) + Math.pow(div1y - div2y, 2);
var distance = Math.sqrt(distanceSquared);
```

Comment: This answer is using jQuery...but if you don't want to use jQuery you could replace the top 2 lines with `var div1rect = document.getElementById("div1").getBoundingClientRect();` ...etc

Comment: I basically need the distance to estimate how likely is a "price" on a site be the price of the product that the site is for. I want to calculate distance between the product image (which I know where is it) and all the prices that are around the page. The price that is closest to the product image is likely to be the price of that product :)

Comment: I am trying it. I will be back and tell you. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem here is that some elements (span) don't have width/height.

Comment: Are you in control of the HTML? If not, I would find another way to get a reasonable location of the price, maybe just use top/left and not using the width/height to get a center point.

Comment: WHat? I don't understand. How would you do it without with/height?

Comment: That depends. Is just using the top/left point of the span good enough? If you have control over the HTML, modify the HTML so that the span's are wrapped inside a div.

Comment: You can get width by subtracting left from right, and you can get height by subtracting top from bottom.