# JavaScript: Get background-position in pixels

Tags: javascript, css, animation, background-position

I am working on a JavaScript animation library and ran into a problem: All values are usually returned in **pixels** using this default function:

```
window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(property);
```

However, when getting the value for background-position like so:

```
window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('background-position');
```

The result is **50% 50%** (background-position: center). How can I convert the values to pixels? I wrote the following function, but it gives me the wrong result, the reason being is that percentages on background-position are also relative to the image size.

```
var pixelsX = (parseFloat(percentX) / 100 * element.offsetWidth) + 'px';
var pixelsY = (parseFloat(percentY) / 100 * element.offsetHeight) + 'px';
```

I also cannot get the size using Image() since the calculation has to happen in real time and I cannot wait for the image to load.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that in some cases I might know the size of the image and I need to calculate it without loading the image.

Comment: The position is relative to the container and to "background-size" which in my case is "auto", so I do not know the size of the background.

Comment: If my container is 100px x 100px and "background-position" is set to "50% 50%" the conversion would be "50px 50px". Which does not equate to "50% 50%", since it would set the top left corner of the background image to "50px 50px".

Comment: For the latter problem, with not having the image loaded, can't you just start your animation using onLoad? `<body onload="startAnimation()">`

Comment: Either you know the size of the image OR the value of background size to do the calculation. More detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333 You will find the formula in the section "Relation between pixel and percentage values"

Answer (score 0):

I actually did tried your code and it works... 
Is this not the accurate sizes? 
I checked it on different screen sizes and it seems accurate.

Please have a look:

```js
var demoDiv = document.getElementById('divDemo');
var demoCalc = window.getComputedStyle(demoDiv).getPropertyValue('background-position');
var pixelsX = (parseFloat(demoCalc) / 100 * demoDiv.offsetWidth) + 'px';
var pixelsY = (parseFloat(demoCalc) / 100 * demoDiv.offsetHeight) + 'px';
console.log(demoCalc);
console.log(pixelsX);
console.log(pixelsY);
```

```css
body {height: 100vh; width: 100vw; overflow: hidden}
#divDemo {
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554056588-6c35fac03654?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=80);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="divDemo"></div>
```

More SO on this subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384016/convert-percent-to-pixel/34385896)

Comment: this will always give the same value whataver the image but the values depends on the image size

Comment: Using Firefox on my desktop with different screen sizes (using the ctrl+m magic) it showed me different results: 480 X 320 showed (232px ,152px) while on 1000 X 800 showed (492px, 392px).

Comment: I was talking about the image, not the screen size. For one screen size you will always have the same value which is wrong because it should be a different one based on the image ... a 50x50 image will not have the same position as a 500x500 image if we consider pixel value (related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734530/8620333)

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but when i change the position to: 10% 10% this give me other results. What is this? the container position or the image?

Comment: when dealing with percentage values in background-position there is two factors to consider: the image **size** and the container **size**. You need both of them to find the position. Try to use two different images with different **size** and consider the same value of background-position and see how both will be placed differently but your code will give the same result because it doesn't consider the image size.

Comment: Thanks you for your explanation. Now i finally understood. I leave this here for future readers for now. I think you should answer it since the link doesn't give all of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the position of the element, maybe try this:

element.getBoundingClientRect();
(source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

You can get the position of each corner as well as dimensions of the element like so:
element.getBoundingClientRect().left;

This returns properties: left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, and height.
All in pixels!